# Unable to delete file from desktop | Windows 10

Tags: permissions, windows-10

There's a video file it's of .wmv format, but I'm not able to delete it from "my desktop".

When I select it and press delete nothing happens.
I can play that file, but it can't be copied somewhere or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you don't have proper access rights to the file. If you're logged in as an administrator, try right clicking the file and going to Properties -> Security. Check the user name you're logged in as and see if you have "Full control" permissions. If not, click the edit button and assign your username with the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Delete using Powershell.

1. Go to search
2. Type "PowerShell".
3. Then right-click it and select "Run as administrator".
4. Run the following command

```
Remove-Item –path c:\users\<yourUsername>\desktop\yourfile.wmv -force
```

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-Item -path c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\today.wmv - force
Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item –path c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\today.wmv - force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: it should be -force , no space. Still, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this; it's working:

```
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\John\Downloads\path-name.mkv" -Force
```

Comment: This is what a previous answer already suggests—or something very similar—and which comments report isn’t working. Can you clarify what the difference is and why you think that solves the problem?